# Update all shapefiles in "Directory of spatial files" with low unavailability

Tags: geoserver, shapefile

I'm starting to work with GeoServer.
I have a list of 20 shapefiles (shp + shx + dbf) to publish on GeoServer and some of the files are updated daily and shared with me normally at 8pm. I need to update these layers in a specific datasource (Directory of spatial files), but I don't know what is the correct way to do it.

My server is an Ubuntu 22 and I have full access, and the source files are on a Windows Server. I'm thinking of the following solution:
Create a share on `SAMBA` outside of the GeoServer directory and automate the company's internal process for copying updated files to this shared folder.
After that I copy all the updated files in that directory to the GeoServer data directory. This copy will be started by `inotifywait` monitoring.

I noticed that this way works correctly, but whenever the layers are updated the server processing reaches almost 100% - and when that happens the map becomes unavailable to the end user. I believe this happens because when the layer file is modified the GeoServer needs to reprocess the layer (each of them).

What is the correct way to update on GeoServer without unavailability for users?

Note: for the final solution it will be two Ubuntu for the GeoServer and a balancer (with HAProxy).

Settings:

**Ubuntu**

- x64
- 8 CPUs (2.20GHz)
- 24GiB RAM
- 500GiB disk

**GeoServer**

- version 2.23.2
- JAVA_OPTS =  -Xms10G -Xmx10G

Comment: don't use a shared directory for data, copy the files into PostGIS and update the tables as needed

Comment: Filesystems are not generally transactional. The problem is using a non-transactional data store like shapefile, which is subject to race conditions.